# Bandwidth limiter in Tomato (by Shibby) does not work

Tags: router, tomato

My device is Linksys E1200V2 and it previously ran **tomato-E1200v2-NVRAM64K-1.28.RT-N5x-MIPSR2-137-Max** but the bandwidth limiter won’t work.

So I Googled around and found a couple threads that said version 132 works so now it’s flashed with **tomato-E1200v2-NVRAM64K-1.28.RT-N5x-MIPSR2-132-Ma"**. However the bandwidth limiter *still* doesn’t work.

I rebooted a hundred times, ran speed test a hundred times, and I get full speed every single time.

I have screenshot my settings here. Could someone help please? Thank you very much.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]